# How to apply texture to UIImageView in MonoTouch

Tags: coding-style, colors, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to style an IPad application written in MonoTouch and I've picked some colours from
http://www.colorcombos.com/combolibrary.html.

Does anyone know of a way to apply a texture to a UIImageView once a background color is applied?

Sort of like the blue-ish background on this website, http://twitter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using the BackgroundColor on the UIImageView, one option is to use multiple UIImageViews.

You can achieve what you want by using transparent PNGs and laying them over top of one another.  The bottom (by Z-order) UIImageView can still set the BackgroundColor as you mention.

Other methods would be to perform the drawing by hand with CGContext, but I'd only pursue that option if you have some kind of perf issue, which you shouldn't.